# Legend Trouble in R- how to change legend text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot in grey with the legend inside the plot. However, the labels in the legend are wrong. If I follow advice to change the legend labels, even without changing the theme, then I'm somehow back to the default colors. There has got to be a better way. "sex" in the legend as "Method", "m" is "1" and "f" is "2" with the plot still gray, would be a huge improvement.

```
require(ggplot2)
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
time <- c(1, 1.3, 1.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.3, 1.1)
sex <- c("m","f","m","f","m","f","m","f","m")
print(myDF <- data.frame(sex, counts, time))

gTest <- ggplot(myDF, aes(counts, time, color=sex)) +
    geom_point(size = 3)+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F) +
    ggtitle("Long-Term Gain in Speech Rate")+
    xlab("Baseline Speech Rate") +
    ylab("Mean Speech Rate Gain")
```

### Thanks! This changes the title

```
gTest + scale_colour_grey(start = .3, end = .7) + guides(color=guide_legend(title="Method")) + theme_bw()+ theme(legend.position=c(.9,.9), legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="white"))
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `gTest + scale_colour_grey(start = .3, end = .7) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Method")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position=c(.9,.9),
        legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",
                                       size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="white"))`

Comment: That changes the title and the plot is still gray. That is very good. Mike, do you know about changing the factor names ("m" is "1" and "f" is "2")?

Comment: Sure, was a little confused about the wording, but here is the code to change the legend labels + title: `gTest + scale_colour_grey(start = .3, end = .7,labels=c("2","1")) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Method")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position=c(.9,.9),
        legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",
                                       size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="white"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the legend labels, you can edit your call to `scale_colour_grey()` to include a `labels=` argument. To change the legend title, you can specify this in your `guides()` call. This should produce the desired result:

```
gTest + scale_colour_grey(start = .3, end = .7,labels=c("2","1")) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Method")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position=c(.9,.9),
        legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",
                                       size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="white"))
```

[image]